# How to find the ratio between a factor column and numeric column?

Tags: r, format, gsub

I have a factor column and a numeric column, of which I need to find the ratio between the two, and then format it so the new variable has two decimal places.

I've tried using as.numeric(as.character()) to convert the factor variable and then divide the two to find the ratio, but the result is a vector of NA. Also, I need to use base r code.

```
x=as.numeric(as.character(TotalElectric)) / Power_from_renew
format(x, digits=2)
```

```
TotalElectric Power_from_renew
1             833         1313.400
2           4,525         8135.400
3          75,200          673.000
4           5,512         7391.300
5             105         2952.000
6         147,000        32523.800
7           7,763         2596.700
8             980         2743.400
9         259,400        37448.000
10         70,100        53853.000
11         24,300         2191.900
12          2,190         2948.400
13         13,086         2847.000
14         74,700         1183.100
15          1,002         2867.100
```

When I used the above code, my result was

```
Power_from_renew
1                 NA
2                 NA
3                 NA
4                 NA
5                 NA
6                 NA
```

I also tried using gsub to format the factor variable, but with the same result.

Comment: `as.numeric(gsub(",","",TotalElectric))` (with or without `as.character` depending on the true nature of your data (the true nature is ambiguous as it stands, it would be clearer to see the output from `dput(head(x))`, or whatever your variable is named ... `dput` is the key.)

Comment: The result is still a variable of NAs even when I use gsub.

Comment: And my suggestion is still: provide unambiguous data, please. Based on the imperfect data we have, *my code works* (both as `character` strings and as `factor`s) to generate numbers from the number-like strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@r2evans solution works perfectly. You are probably doing something wrong.

```
# > tst
# TotalElectric Power_from_renew
# 1           833           1313.4
# 2         4,525           8135.4
# 3        75,200            673.0
# 4         5,512           7391.3
# 5           105           2952.0
# 6       147,000          32523.8
# 7         7,763           2596.7
# 8           980           2743.4
# 9       259,400          37448.0
# 10        70,100          53853.0
# 11        24,300           2191.9
# 12         2,190           2948.4
# 13        13,086           2847.0
# 14        74,700           1183.1
# 15         1,002           2867.1

tst <- as.data.frame(tst)
class(tst$TotalElectric)
# [1] "factor"
class(tst$Power_from_renew)
# [1] "numeric"

x=as.numeric(as.numeric(gsub(",","",tst$TotalElectric))) / tst$Power_from_renew

format(x, digits=2)
#   [1] "  0.634" "  0.556" "111.738" "  0.746" "  0.036" "  4.520" "  2.990" "  0.357" "  6.927" "  1.302" " 11.086" "  0.743" "  4.596"
#   [14] " 63.139" "  0.349"
```